# How to remove Duplicates given a Random String of letters in Google Sheets?

Tags: string, google-sheets

I have been trying to find all duplicates within a string of letters, but I do not know where to start.

I had stretched out of all of the letters into separate tiles thinking that I would be able to use to compare tiles with If Then statements. [image]

I tried to manually compare each letter with if(b1=b2,"Ignore",b1). This could work, but I would have to type out the grid coordinates to compare all 81 combinations for the string.

Comment: ```=UNIQUE(YOUR_DATA)```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=BYROW(A10:A11, LAMBDA(x, JOIN(, UNIQUE(REGEXEXTRACT(x&"", REPT("(.)", LEN(x))), 1))))
```

[image]

if the latter case does not matter you can do:

```
=BYROW(A10:A11, LAMBDA(x, JOIN(, UNIQUE(REGEXEXTRACT(LOWER(x)&"", REPT("(.)", LEN(x))), 1))))
```

[image]